# Using the fsc mount option with nfsroot kernel parameter to allow FS-cache

Tags: boot, mount, nfs, initramfs, pxe

I'm PXE-booting a Ubuntu 10.10 system, where I specify the kernel parameters as follows:

```
append root=/dev/nfs initrd=ubuntu-boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-24-generic
nfsroot=11.22.33.44:/data/nfsroot,fsc ip=dhcp rw
```

I need to use the mount option 'fsc' in order to use FS-cache functionality (the cachefilesd package.) However, when I try this I get the following error upon boot:

```
nfsmount: bad option 'fsc'
```

Why doesn't nfsmount permit this option? (It works fine when you mount manually with `mount -o fsc` after booting up.)

I changed nfsmount to `mount -t nfs` in the file `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/nfs` and then I ran `update-initramfs -u` to update the initramfs image, but it seems this still gives an error:

```
mount: unknown nfs mount option 'fsc'
```

My guess would be that this is a limitation of the mount functionality in **klibc**. What would be the best way to address this? Does the nfsmount program need to be patched?

Since this seems to be a limitation of the nfsmount tool in klibc, I was thinking that I could add `/sbin/mount.nfs` to the initramfs image and mount the nfsroot with this tool instead. I copied it into the folder `/usr/lib/klibc/bin` and I updated the script `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/nfs` as follows:

```
mount.nfs ${NFSROOT} ${rootmnt} -o nolock ${roflag} ${NFSOPTS}
```

After booting the updated initramfs image, there is a long delay when mount.nfs is executed and then the following message is displayed:

```
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified  
Begin: Retrying nfs mount ... Begin: Running /scripts/nfs-premount ... done.
```

However, this message is displayed no matter what mount options I use, so it appears to be a different problem altogether...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally manged to solve it. Here are the steps:

1. Add mount.nfs from Ubuntu 10.04 to the initramfs image (copy it into the `/usr/lib/klibc/bin folder`.)
2. Change the nfsmount line in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/nfs` to:

   ```
   mount.nfs ${NFSROOT} ${rootmnt} -o nolock ${roflag} ${NFSOPTS}
   ```
3. Update the initramfs image with either `mkinitramfs` or `update-initramfs`.

This would enable the fsc option on the nfsroot for my Ubuntu 10.10 system. I have no idea why I'm not able to use mount.nfs from 10.10 though -- perhaps a regression?

Comment: Ah, good idea! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Recently I was building a new nfsroot based on 16.04 and decided to take another look at using cachefilesd for the nfsroot file system.  Yet again I stumbled on this post.  It helped to get me pointed in the right direction, and I ended up getting it to work but I believe I have a better answer than the one posted here.

While meanderix's steps could work I don't think its the best way.  So here are my steps:

1. In `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks` create a new file.  I called mine `fsc` for file system cache.
2. Add the following content to your file:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh 
   set -e
   PREREQ=""
   prereqs () {
           echo "${PREREQ}"
   }  
   case "${1}" in
           prereqs)
                   prereqs
                   exit 0
                   ;;
   esac
   . /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions
   copy_exec /sbin/mount.nfs /sbin
   exit 0
   ```
3. Make the fsc file executable:

   ```
   chmod 755 /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsc
   ```
4. Modify `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/nfs` as meanderix suggests.
5. Generate your initramfs. eg:

   ```
   mkinitramfs -o /fscinitrd
   ```

The difference and the real magic here is the `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsc` file.  Particularly the `copy_exec` line.  When the initial RAM disk is created it will automatically add `mount.nfs` to the initramfs.  But wait there's more!  It will also determine the libraries needed and add them for you too.  That's really cool since on Ubuntu 16.04 I needed `libtirpc.so` since `mount.nfs` was dependent on it and this added those dependencies for me.

After doing this and configuring cachefilesd I now have file system caching for my NFSROOT and that's just awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel has not been compiled with that module (CONFIG_NFS_FSCACHE in kernel config).
And a link to a guide for that: [Ubuntu Kernel/Compile](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile)

Comment: It is compiled with it, I use the feature all the time (but just in /etc/fstab), I suspect maybe the nfsmount tool in userspace doesn't support this or something?

Comment: I found the following bug report that seems to indicate that it has been added in Maverick:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/440522

Comment: My fstab entry also specifies the fsc option, but it seems to be ignored:

/dev/nfs /               nfs fsc  1       1

Comment: Thanks, Jorge and meanderix. Mysterious. Interesting. Seems like a bounty question? This is a great feature to get working right.

Comment: I'm new in this community, but if it's possible to promote the question I think that would be great.

Comment: I am new, too. I can only start a bounty on my own questions. But I have not given up... just no new ideas yet. There are some very smart and nice people here - hoping someone gleans the solution. I would like to implement the same goal.

Comment: Here's a Debian bug report that describes a similar error: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=359926. Looks like the solution would be to change nfsmount to "mount -t nfs", but I'm not sure exactly which initramfs script I need to edit to achieve this.

Comment: Ok, I changed nfsmount to "mount -t nfs" in the file /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/nfs and then I ran "update-initramfs -u", but it seems this still gives an error: "mount: unknown nfs mount option 'fsc'"

Comment: @meanderix Add what you try to the original question, that gives it a bump and puts all the info at the top instead of buried in the comments!